# Time Complexity of Interval Sum

Tags: java, algorithm, time, time-complexity

I'm trying to understand time complexities of algorithms and came across this problem. The problem is to calculate interval sum (0 <= k <= length_of_list).

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    LinkedList<Integer> l=new LinkedList<Integer>();
    l.add(4);
    l.add(2);
    l.add(3);
    l.add(1);
    l.add(5);

    int k=2;

    List result = new ArrayList();
    int n = l.size();

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if(i >= k-1){
            int sum = 0;
            for(int j = i; j >= i-k+1; j--){
                sum += in.get(j);
            }
            result.add(sum);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Can someone explain me the time complexity of the above code? Is it n*k or n^2 (because k's maximum value is n). Does if condition affect time complexities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner loop is executed O(n-k) times due to the `if` being this many times, which is O(n).
The inner loop is O(k) - that how many times it iterates.

The overall algorithm is then O(n) * O(k) = O(n * k).

You could argue it's O((n - k) * k), but for k << n, that's the same as O(n * k).

For the edge case of k being close to n in size, the complexity would be O(n), because the `if` would be true O(1) times, and the inner loop would O(k), which is O(n) for k ~ n, so O(n) overall.

Comment: Thanks. This helped me a lot.

Comment: Does this mean, best case is O(n)(for k ~ n) and worst case is O(n*k)(for k << n).

Comment: @user1092: your code is O(n * k), but there exists pure O(n) solution without consider k value.

Comment: @algojava although that is true, it's not relevant to the question

Comment: @Bohemian: I know, I just share the information for him.